# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows...when Insert Indentity Column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
Insert into Goals(UserID) values (@UserID)
Insert into ActivityGoals(GoalsID, ActivityID, Longest, Total, Start, [End]) 
values ((Select SCOPE_IDENTITY() from Goals), @ActivityID, @Longest, @Total, @Start, @End)
```

How to fix an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` only returns one value; it cannot return more than one.  The problem is that you have this query:

```
select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
from goals
```

This returns *one* value for every row in `goals` -- your problem.

Try this:

```
Insert into Goals(UserID) values (@UserID);

Insert into ActivityGoals(GoalsID, ActivityID, Longest, Total, Start, [End]) 
    Select SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @ActivityID, @Longest, @Total, @Start, @End);
```

Although this will work under almost all circumstances, the safest way to do this is using the `output` clause for `insert`:

```
declare @OutputIds table (id int); 
insert into Goals(UserID)
    output inserted.GoalId into @OutputIds
    values (@UserID);

Insert into ActivityGoals(GoalsID, ActivityID, Longest, Total, Start, [End]) 
    Select id, @ActivityID, @Longest, @Total, @Start, @End)
    from @OutputIds;
```

This also has the advantage (if you want) that you can insert multiple rows and capture all the ids.

Comment: I added a missing keyword.  If you set up a SQL Fiddle, I can test it.

Comment: Thanks! I made done! Use `Select SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead `(Select SCOPE_IDENTITY() from Goals)`

Answer (score 1):

One basic solution is:

```
    Insert into ActivityGoals(GoalsID, ActivityID, Longest, Total, Start, [End]) 
    values ((Select TOP 1 SCOPE_IDENTITY() from Goals ), @ActivityID, @Longest, @Total, @Start, @End)
```

But the best one would be to determine yourself in the query to return only one element.

The `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function might return more than one value. For info about [scope_identity()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` cannot return more than one value.  SQL Server has no functions in the `select` clause that result in multiplying the number of rows in the result set.